# Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:0) with 7616000 bytes to a Java Buffer with 1411200 bytes

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensor, yolov5

i'm getting this error when i try to run my tflite model of yolov5 with a modified architecture on android studio (app mobile).
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=106KB, data=61KB
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 6210
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:0) with 7616000 bytes to a Java Buffer with 1411200 bytes.
at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfDstShapeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:472)
at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:252)
at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:175)
at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:360)
at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.YoloV5Classifier.recognizeImage(YoloV5Classifier.java:391)
at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity$2.run(DetectorActivity.java:246)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

Can somone help me to slove this problem?